# Как перевести Json формат в "понятный" текст?

Tags: c#, json, winforms

Я знакомлюсь с VK API, и воспользовался WebClient'ом для выполнения Get запроса. Всё проходит гладко, но текст как и нужно, отображается на textbox'е в формате Json. Возможно ли перевести его в "нормальный" для пользователя текст?

Comment: Парсить json....

Comment: @Flippy Можно пример? Вот код: http://imgur.com/HGainhn

Comment: http://java-help.ru/android-json > Работа с JSON в Java

Answer (score 1):

Используйте dll от Newtonsoft. Она умеет разбирать/собирать JSON из объектов. Скачать и посмотреть документацию можно [здесь](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).